# vb.net connects to database access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

im really new to this language so this is so simple please answer

Me.InfoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

i only have id t on my delete button do i have to adsome codes? knows anyone?
i've searched some sites and it is the only code they say. i connected it and actually worked on add. but with delete it dont.

Do i need to move something.. like files?
i've tried everything this is my last hope. thanks for the answer :)
here is the whole code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.InfoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That `RemoveCurrent` method will mark the current row in the bound `DataTable` as `Deleted`.  Just like when adding or editing rows though, you still have to call `Update` on your data adapter or table adapter to save that change back to the database.

Comment: Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet) is it the update your saying? thanks

Comment: `UpdateAll` will work as it will call `Update` on each table adapter.

Comment: i see that from the binding navigator where should i put it?

Comment: Are you asking where you should call `UpdateAll`?  If so then think about when you want the changes to be saved and what event is raised at that point.  You should generally just have a "Save" button and put your code to save in its `Click` event handler.  The user can then make as many changes of whatever kind they like and then save them all in one batch with one click.